# How to lift a function to work on lenses?

Tags: haskell, lenses

I currently have defined two functions:

```
avg :: (Fractional e) => [e] -> e
avg e = uncurry (/) $ foldl' (\(a,l) v -> (a+v,l+1)) (0.0,0.0) e

avgOf :: (Fractional a) => Getting (Endo (Endo (a, a))) s a -> s -> a
avgOf g s = uncurry (/) $ foldlOf' g accfun (0.0,0.0) s
  where accfun (a,l) v = (a+v, l+1)
```

I am under the impression that there has to be an easy way to get rid of the whole `avgOf` implementation and replace that with a simple one that just 'lifts' `avg` to work on lenses.

Comment: I think the obvious solution would be avgOf l = avg . toListOf l

Comment: If that works that's definitely the easiest thing to do. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: It works. But you have to give the other parameter too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`partsOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/lens/latest/doc/html/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v%3apartsOf) to construct this out of whole cloth.

```
avgOf l xs = xs^..partsOf l.to avg
```